# How to extract a value from a string using regex and a shell?

Tags: regex, shell

I am in shell and I have this string: `12 BBQ ,45 rofl, 89 lol`

Using the regexp: `\d+ (?=rofl)`, I want `45` as a result.

Is it correct to use regex to extract data from a string? The best I have done is to highlight the value in some of the online regex editor. Most of the time it remove the value from my string.

I am investigating `expr`, but all I get is syntax errors.

How can I manage to extract 45 in a shell script?

Comment: IMHO for this purpose, using Regex is completely acceptable.

Comment: What tool do you use, what shell do you use, what's the exact commandline you used and what's the error you got?

Comment: A comprehensive answer from Unix.SE: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/193223/regular-expression-to-extract-information-in-shell-script

Answer (score 98, accepted):

You can do this with GNU grep's perl mode:

```
echo "12 BBQ ,45 rofl, 89 lol" | grep -P '\d+ (?=rofl)' -o
echo "12 BBQ ,45 rofl, 89 lol" | grep --perl-regexp '\d+ (?=rofl)' --only-matching
```

`-P` and `--perl-regexp` mean Perl-style regular expression.
`-o` and `--only-matching` mean to output only the matching text.

Comment: Is it possible to avoid usage of perl-style, because it's removed from grep in OS X since Mountain Lion?

Comment: Possible alternative/workaround for OS X is using of gnu grep via homebrew, http://www.heystephenwood.com/2013/09/install-gnu-grep-on-mac-osx.html.

Comment: I can retrieve the port number of docker containers :D with `docker port c62c1c7b9efb | grep -P '(\d+)$' -o`

Comment: Seems in busybox it's `-E` instead of `-P`

Comment: There is a suggested edit that with BSD grep (e.g., on a Mac), it would be `-E` instead of `-P`, but I believe that won't work, since `-P` in GNU Grep is for Perl mode, while `-E` in (most?) greps is extended mode, which is quite different. I just tested a different version's `-E` option and it output nothing instead of the expected `45`.

Comment: @Charlie Does using `-E` on busybox actually give the output `45` as expected?

Comment: @joanis no, it does not. It appears the regexp in this specific example is not compatible. However, -P is an invalid option in busybox, and -E is "extended regexp" https://busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html#:~:text=PATTERN%20is%20an%20extended%20regular%20expression -E worked for the regex I was trying to use.

Comment: @Charlie Thanks for the confirmation. So to use this specific solution on a Mac, one has the follow the instructions (shared in another comment above) about installing GNU Grep on a Mac.

Answer (score 36):

Yes regex can certainly be used to extract part of a string. Unfortunately different flavours of *nix and different tools use slightly different Regex variants.

This sed command should work on most flavours (Tested on OS/X and Redhat)

```
echo '12 BBQ ,45 rofl, 89 lol' | sed  's/^.*,\([0-9][0-9]*\).*$/\1/g'
```

Comment: You don't need the anchors if your regex begins and ends with `.*`

Comment: Also +1. Your answer is POSIX-compliant where the accepted answer is not, as the accepted answer uses the nonstandard `-P` `grep` option

Comment: I'm using this on macOS where zsh is the default by wrapping the command in `/bin/sh -c "command"`. Works nicely!

Answer (score 9):

It seems that you are asking multiple things. To answer them:

- Yes, it is ok to extract data from a string using regular expressions, that's what they're there for
- You get errors, which one and what shell tool do you use?
- You can extract the numbers by catching them in capturing parentheses:

  ```
  .*(\d+) rofl.*
  ```

  and using `$1` to get the string out (`.*` is for "the rest before and after on the same line)

With sed as example, the idea becomes this to replace all strings in a file with only the matching number:

```
sed -e 's/.*(\d+) rofl.*/$1/g' inputFileName > outputFileName
```

or:

```
echo "12 BBQ ,45 rofl, 89 lol" | sed -e 's/.*(\d+) rofl.*/$1/g'
```

Comment: You don't need either of the `.*` in your example. You only need those on edges if your regex is anchored. Unanchored, it will already match anywhere inside the string.

Comment: The OP asked to get only the number out, not to do a succesful match. By adding `.*`, it's a simple way to match everything and replace by what's in the matching parentheses. Without them, the rest of the string remains intact, which is not what was asked (iiuc). Or did I miss something perhaps?

Comment: Woops, I missed that you were using `sed` for this. Carry on.

Comment: What implementation of sed are you using? `$1` in craziness

Comment: @harold, this was 8 years ago, can't remember. What do you mean with $1 is craziness? It's how you refer to captured substrings in basically any regex flavour.

Comment: @Abel I guess "craziness" is a bit much. I mean to say it is not remotely portable (as far as POSIX is concerned). In fact, your answer does not work on the `sed`s that come with Ubuntu 14.04, Ubuntu 18.04 and FreeBSD 11 (both because of the non-portable `\d` and that fact that `$1` is treated literally in this context)

Comment: @harold, interesting, I didn't know that. I personally use different tools most of the time with more perl like syntax. But in the absence of a standard (xsd and xpath 3.0 describe some standard, but that's for those technologies only) and all different versions in existence, it can be tricky to make a single expression work everywhere. I know I tested before posting, but perhaps I should update (or you can if you want, if you know a better command, feel free to do so)

Comment: @Abel Also, sed uses basic regular expressions, and as such, `(\d+)` should be written as `\(\d+\)` if it is to be treated as a subexpression

Comment: @Abel Just thought I would mention it to you. Steve Weet has answered the question properly, except that he did not need to put anchors around his regex

Comment: @harold, thanks, your comments are appreciated. I don't like wrong answers to stay around, and I'm now starting to wonder how I came to this one. Once back home behind a laptop (I'm on my phone right now) I'll have a fresh look.

Answer (score 6):

Using [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep)'s [replace](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep/blob/master/GUIDE.md#replacements) option, it is possible to change the output to a capture group:

```
rg --only-matching --replace '$1' '(\d+) rofl'
```

- `--only-matching` or `-o` outputs only the part that matches instead of the whole line.
- `--replace '$1'` or `-r` replaces the output by the first capture group.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the shell(bash for example)

```
$ string="12 BBQ ,45 rofl, 89 lol"
$ echo ${string% rofl*}
12 BBQ ,45
$ string=${string% rofl*}
$ echo ${string##*,}
45
```

Comment: Useful link - https://aty.sdsu.edu/bibliog/latex/debian/bash.html

Answer (score -1):

You can certainly extract that part of a string and that's a great way to parse out data. Regular expression syntax varies a lot so you need to reference the help file for the regex you're using. You might try a regular expression like:

```
[0-9]+ *[a-zA-Z]+,([0-9]+) *[a-zA-Z]+,[0-9]+ *[a-zA-Z]+
```

If your regex program can do string replacement then replace the entire string with the result you want and you can easily use that result.

You didn't mention if you're using bash or some other shell. That would help get better answers when asking for help.

Answer (score -2):

You can use [rextract](https://github.com/kata198/rextract) to extract using a regular expression and reformat the result.

Example:

```
[$] echo "12 BBQ ,45 rofl, 89 lol" | ./rextract '[,]([\d]+) rofl' '${1}'
45
```

Comment: You need to add a disclaimer if a library is your own (something like "  Disclaimer: I made this library   "). And from github, it does appear that this library / executable is your own