# using sed to find a value given a regex

Tags: regex, macos, sed, macos-high-sierra

I am trying to get a value from some output. Let's say I want the `id` property of this json object:

```
{"id":123,"useless1":"uselessValue","useless2":uselessValue}
```

I tried this:

```
a={"id":123,"useless1":"uselessValue","useless2":uselessValue}
echo $a | sed -e s/.*"id":(\d+).*/$1/g
```

But it returns `{"id":123,"useless1":"uselessValue","useless2":uselessValue}`

I also tried [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3320480/1967800)

If I copy:

```
echo "12 BBQ ,45 rofl, 89 lol" | sed -e 's/.*(\d+) rofl.*/$1/g'
```

I get:

```
12 BBQ ,45 rofl, 89 lol
```

Instead of `45`

I am using MacOs High Sierra (10.13.6)

Comment: The `sed` command should look like `sed -e 's/.*"id":\([0-9][0-9]*\).*/\1/'`. Can't you use `jq` to parse JSON?

Comment: Oh! It works... Thank you.

Comment: For my use case, it is better to stick to this.

Comment: It's not, unless you parse the same JSON that will never change, in which case there's no need to parse anything.

Comment: Yes, I see, it is not quite  a valid JSON. `uselessValue` should  be in double quotes. Unless you manually "ruined" JSON structure.

Comment: It is just that I only need the id, I'm confident enough about the json structure, and it is more important for my use case to not rely on a dependency than to parse the whole JSON. Thanks a lot for your help anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `jq`, it will be as easy as

```
jq '.id' file
```

If you want to fix your `sed` command, make sure to use BRE POSIX compliant pattern and `\1` placeholder in the RHS:

```
sed -e 's/.*"id":\([0-9][0-9]*\).*/\1/'
```

POIs:

- Capturing groups are defined with `\(...\)`
- One or more digits are matched with `[0-9][0-9]*`